# adding ShareKit to my project, won't compile - 4,448 errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, frameworks, sharekit

I can get the ShareKit demo from github to compile using the iOS 4.1 SDK, but when I import it into my project exactly how it's described on the ShareKit site, after compiling I'm getting 4,448 errors. It looks like I'm missing a framework, but I have the required frameworks listed. Maybe there's some kind of framework conflict. Here are some screenshots:

[image: sharekit1]

The frameworks:

[image: sharekit2]

[image: sharekit build settings]

Has anyone else seen this before? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to compile a pure-C file with some Objective-C mixed in.  I'd make sure that all the files have a source type of "sourcecode.c.objc" (which you can do by selecting the file and typing <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd>)

Comment: thank you! well, that got rid of 4,447 errors, but now i'm stuck with a weird link error... "Symbol(s) not found" screenshot: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20013/temp/sharekit4.png - i tried clean all, and to empty xcode's caches, to no avail. any ideas on that one?

Comment: oops nevermind - i didn't read that carefully enough and just renamed the files as source.c.objc. haha. and that was causing them to be copied as bundle resources instead of compiled sources. doh. thanks a lot dave!